# View stdout and logs of an ephemeral docker container

Tags: docker

I understand there are many questions about how to read docker logs that are answered by:

```
$ docker logs containername
```

However, I am working with an ephemeral container, one created with -rm, so I do not have time to call logs after creating it.  But I am still interested in seeing the logs of how it ran.

My command is:

```
docker run --name myname --rm  python-my-script:3.7.4 - --myflags "myargs"
```

Now, I'd like to see how my script runs with these arguments.  My entrypoint has a script that should effectively be reading in and printing "myargs" to the console.

But when I do:

```
docker logs myname
Error: No such container: myname
```

Or if I'm really quick:

```
Error response from daemon: can not get logs from container which is dead or marked for removal
```

How can I see the logs of a container that is no longer running?  I'd prefer not to install something heavyweight like syslog.

Comment: Have you tried running it in foreground mode? https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: Since I am not using the -d flag, I believe foreground is the default, right?

Comment: seems like your container is not running. you should better try to run your `-it` flag to check if there is any thing that killed your container. checking logs is then next step

Comment: I understand how to call docker interactively using the -it flags, that's not my objective with this question. The process ran quickly, and rm'd itself on completion as I asked it to.  I am looking for stderr and stdout for while it was running, after it has stopped running.

Answer (score 4):

The default logging driver for Docker is `json-file`, which you are able to use `docker logs` to see it. But if you delete the container or use `--rm` when run the container, the logs will be deleted after the container removed.

For you case, you need change a logging driver to assure the log still could be seen even after the container deleted.

There are a lots of logging driver which could meet your requirements, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers). E.g fluentd, splunk, etc.

Here, give a simplest way to reserve the log, use [journald](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/), a minimal example for your reference:

1. Start the container with journald log driver, need to set a container name which will be used later to retrieve the log:

   ```
   $ docker run --log-driver=journald --rm --name=trial alpine echo "hello world"
   ```
2. After the container finish print "hello world", the container will be deleted as it specify `--rm`, check if `docker logs` ok:

   ```
   $ docker logs trial
   Error: No such container: trial
   ```
3. Use journald to if we can get the log:

   ```
   $ journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=trial --all
   -- Logs begin at Mon 2018-12-17 21:35:55 CST, end at Mon 2019-08-05 14:21:19 CST. --
   Aug 05 14:18:26 shubuntu1 a475febe91c1[1975]: hello world
   ```

You can see you can use journalctl to get the log content "hello world" even the container was removed.

BTW, if you do not want to specify `--log-driver` every time you start a container, you can also set it as default log driver in `daemon.json`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/#usage):

```
{
  "log-driver": "journald"
}
```

Meanwhile, you still can use `docker logs` to get the logs if the container not deleted.